# Why Second navigation moves on top of first one

Tags: html, css, inline

I am working with the display: inline; option again for 2 navigations on the same nav bar. I have done one of these before and had a question sort of related to it; however, I seem to have ran into an issue where the second navigation is on top of the first (in other words the "contact" hovers over the "home" tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/x64qax1x/

I think it must be due to some of my css code for the navs.

```
#nav-container {

/* Spans the width of the page */
width: 100%; 
height: 56px; 
/* no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
margin: 0;
/* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
z-index: 99; 
position: relative; 
background-color: #366b82;

}

#nav {

height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
margin: 0;
/* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
position: absolute; 
border-right: 1px solid #54879d 
}

#nav li {

height: auto;
/* Each menu item is 150px wide */
width: 150px;
/* This lines up the menu items horizontally */  
float: left;
/* All text in the center of the box */
text-align: center; 
/* Removes the default (bullets)*/ 
list-style: none;  
font: normal bold 15px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #366b82;
display: inline;

}

#nav a {

padding: 18px 0;
/*light color effect to separate tabs */
border-left: 1px solid #54879d;
/*dark color effect to separate tabs */
border-right: 1px solid #1f5065;
text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
color: white; /* Text color is white */
display: block;
}
.text-left {

float: left;
padding-left: 30px;
}

.text-right {

float: right;
padding-right: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you are using `position: absolute` which takes your nav out of the flow of the document. You're also using the same `id` for your navs. `id` can only be used once on a page.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x64qax1x/1/)

Add new ids, target the second nav and add `top: 50px` to move it down. But you'll still have hover issues.

Comment: Oh ya... I always seem to bypass that option so many times. I also have been told about using the id only once per page; however, I have learned that you can actually. I did separate my other website's nav before but it did no "change" in comparison

Comment: If I just remove the absolute then both navs are "inline" which solves my issue. I don't actually want the "Contact" below all of them but aligned to the right. (seen in my class for "text-right") Thanks :)